# Rails: updating joined Active Model's attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, activemodel, associated-object

I'm new to RoR.
My question is about updating associated Active Model's attr.

```
class User
  has_many :toys
end

class Toy
  belongs_to :user
end
```

and I have a page with a form of user where I can update user's attributes, and also certain attributes of associated user_devices:

```
<%= f.text_field :age %> # from user
<%= f.text_field :email %> # from user
....
<%= f.check_box :is_new %> # from toy!!
```

When I post the form and update all the attributes using update_attributes(), it shows "ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error"

```
@user.update_attributes(params[:user]) # it gives ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error
```

Another problem is, I don't know how to name the "is_new" attribute as it's in toy table.. Should it be :toys_is_new?

I want the associated toy's attributes to be updated as well. Can you help me with this?

Comment: reason is http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html .. please read and implement.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I found [this link](http://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.3/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods/accepts_nested_attributes_for) helped a lot as well.

Comment: BTW, is it possible on rails 3.2.13? Is there any workaround for this version?

Answer (score 1):

Because `is_new?` is from `Toy`, you have to use [`accepts_nested_attributes_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html):

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :toys
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :toys
end

#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def edit
    @user = User.find params[:id]
  end

  def update
    @user = User.find params[:id]
    @user.update user_params
  end

  private

  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:age, :email, toys_attributes: [:is_new])
  end
end
```

To get this to work in the `view`, you'll need to use the [`fields_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html) helper:

```
#app/views/users/edit.html.erb
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :toys, @user.toys do |t| %>
    <%= t.object.name %>
    <%= t.check_box :is_new %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi @rich peck, Thank you for the help. I passed mess updating error, but another comes here: *** TypeError Exception: can't convert Symbol into String. It comes from user_params method; it seems the interpreter doesn't recognize :user symbol.

Comment: oh damn.. I forgot to mention that I'm using rails 3.2.13!

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [Strong Parameters](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters). It was introduced in Rails 4.

Example:

You have a model `User` with `id`, `firstname`, `lastname`, `email`. The user should only be able to update the first and lastname.

**Your View:**

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :firstname %>
  <%= f.text_field :lastname %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

**Your Controller:**

```
before_action :set_user

def edit
end

def create
  if @user.update user_params
     # Set success message
     # redirect to proper site
  else
     # Set error
     render :edit
  end
end


private

def set_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])    # Rescue against ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound error
end

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:firstname, :lastname)   # Here the strong parameters stuff happens
end
```

If you want to permit more parameters you just have to add them to the `permit` method call.

You got this error just for security reasons.

You can disable Strong Parameters with `config.action_controller.permit_all_parameters = true` but I highly recommend you to use this feature.